# Detect when a PrintDocument successfully prints (not just previewed)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I'm doing some custom printing using a [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) in my application. I have a requirement of logging when our items are successfully printed. I originally achieved this with something like:

```
 print_doc.EndPrint += (o,e) => printed_callback ();
```

To make my `printed_callback` get invoked when a print finished. However, now that I'm adding preview support, I'm passing a `PrintDocument` constructed in exactly the same way into a [PrintPreviewDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printpreviewdialog.aspx). Doing so causes the `EndPrint` event to be invoked after the initial rendering of the printout needed for the preview.

As a result, even if a user clicks "Preview" and then just closes the preview, our logging code gets invoked.

Any suggestions for how to differentiate between a real printout and a "preview print" ? Unfortunately, I can't just not hook up to `EndPrint` for the `PrintDocument` passed to the `PrintPreviewDialog` since the user may click the "Print" button in the preview dialog and trigger a printout.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, so I actually managed to figure this out myself, using the [PrintDocument.PrintController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printcontroller.aspx) property, and checking the `IsPreview` property of the controller. My final coded ended up as follows:

```
doc.EndPrint += (o,e) =>
{
    if (doc.PrintController.IsPreview)
        return;

    print_callback ();
}
```

Comment: double +1, for question and answer :-D

Comment: The above method is when all pages in the PrintDocument have been spooled. It does not check if the job has completed. If you want to check when the job has completed, look at [PrintQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I too managed to figure out a different way that worked for me...

I had a list of MyPrintFileDetail classes each containing a PrintDocument and a StreamReader for said document.

While setting up my PrintDocument, I added an PrintPage event. In the PrintPage event handler I identified which PrintDocument I was working with via casting the "sender" to a PrintDocument.  Then wrote a foreach loop to identify the working MyPrintFileDetail object from the list to get the StreamReader I was using to print. Once there were no more lines to print, I disposed of the StreamReader and set it to null.

Then within my Timer callback for processing the list of MyPrintFileDetail objects, I checked the StreamReader for null and if null, I was done printing.

Kind of clunky but it worked.

```
    private void PD_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument p = (PrintDocument)sender;

        PrintFileDetail pfdWorkingOn = null;

        foreach (PrintFileDetail pfd in pfds)
        {
            if (pfd._PrintDoc.DocumentName == p.DocumentName)
            {
                pfdWorkingOn = pfd;
                break;
            }
        }

        float yPos = 0f;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        string line = null;
        float linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / _TextFilePrintingFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

        while (count < linesPerPage)
        {
            line = pfdWorkingOn._TxtFileBeingPrinted.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            yPos = topMargin + count * _TextFilePrintingFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(line, _TextFilePrintingFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
            count++;
        }

        if (line != null)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pfdWorkingOn._TxtFileBeingPrinted.Dispose();
            pfdWorkingOn._TxtFileBeingPrinted = null;
        }
    }
```