# How do I determine whether I'm printing or previewing?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect when a PrintDocument successfully prints (not just previewed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270546/detect-when-a-printdocument-successfully-prints-not-just-previewed)

I'm using a `PrintDocument` to print a single page of data. Printing and previewing is all working perfectly. What I need to do, however, is determine whether I'm printing or previewing. I can't see from the `BeginPrint`, `PrintPage` or `EndPrint` events that I'm using where I can tell what mode I'm being used in. Any hints?

Clarification edit: I obviously know whether I've invoked `Print()` or I've started a preview with `PrintPreviewDialog` -- but what I need to know is whether the user has subsequently printed the document by printing from the print preview.

Comment: Found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270546/detect-when-a-printdocument-successfully-prints-not-just-previewed